# General relativity, Linealized gravity -- which transformations are compatible with the metric?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, gravitational-waves, lorentz-symmetry, linearized-theory

I am following lecture notes on linearised gravity. The author states that Lorentz transformations are compatible with the metric and begins to Lorentz transform (1) the metric components (2) all vectors and matrices in tangent spaces. Why is this legal, what are the interpretation of the transformed vectors, matrices and metric tensor?

Answer (score 0):

Well, given a first-order split $$ g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu}+h_{\mu\nu}, $$ and a linear Lorentz-transformation of the coordinates $x^{\mu'}=\Lambda^\mu_{\nu}x^\nu$, we have $$ g_{\mu'\nu'}=(\Lambda^{-1})^\mu_{\mu'}(\Lambda^{-1})^\nu_{\nu'}g_{\mu\nu}= (\Lambda^{-1})^\mu_{\mu'}(\Lambda^{-1})^\nu_{\nu'}(\eta_{\mu\nu}+h_{\mu\nu})=\eta_{\mu'\nu'}+h_{\mu'\nu'},$$ where $h_{\mu'\nu'}=(\Lambda^{-1})^\mu_{\mu'}(\Lambda^{-1})^\nu_{\nu'}h_{\mu\nu}$, and $\eta$ stays the same because $\eta$ is preserved by Lorentz transforms.

This transformation preserves the form of the $g=\eta+h$ split, therefore it is a valid transformation.

Comment: The spacetime is not flat, so you can't use Lorentz transformations? Or can you justify that this is possible? does this address the questions?

Comment: What stops you from defining the functions $x^{\mu'}(x^0,x^1,x^2,x^3)=\Lambda^{\mu'}_{\ \mu}x^\mu$?

Comment: Non flat spacetime? Perhaps you can explain in more steps? That way perhaps first time readers will understand more easily? Second, is it possible to address the questions in the thread? Thanks for your time

Comment: @MariusJonsson What I am trying to say is that you don't need flat spacetime to use Lorentz transformations. You can view your current coordinates as 4 variables, and you can define 4 functions via the formula I gave above. Then you apply the tensor component transformation law, and things work out.

As for your questions, I *did* answer them, just implicitly. It is "legal", because any transformation is legal that preserves the $g=\eta+h$ split and as I have shown you, Lorentz transformations do preserve it....

Comment: @MariusJonsson ... And there are no extra interpretations. This is essentially a gauge transformation. All transformed quantities have the same meaning. It is a gauge transformation, because the $g=\eta+h$ split means that it is possible to define "nearly cartesian" coordinate systems. Since Lorentz transforms work between cartesian systems, a Lorentz transform will transform nearly cartesian systems into nearly cartesian systems.